# EF Core 3.1 isn't returning proper errors in migration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a long lasted the switched frameworks multiple times
Long story short, we are using ASP Core 3.1 now, and I'm trying to use EF Migrations

I'm using this command in CL

```
ef migrations add Init --context UsersContext --verbose
```

after building and wrestling with it to find the right Context Configuration, I'm stuck at this error

```
System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
   at System.DBNull.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter`2.Sanitize[T](Object value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter`2.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`2.<SanitizeConverter>b__0(Object v)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDefaultValue(IProperty property)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Initialize(ColumnOperation columnOperation, IProperty property, CoreTypeMapping typeMapping, Boolean isNullable, IEnumerable`1 migrationsAnnotations, Boolean inline)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Add(IProperty target, DiffContext diffContext, Boolean inline)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.CastIterator[TResult](IEnumerable source)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Add(TableMapping target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IModel source, IModel target)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
```

Now the error its self is clear and there are plenty of resources on it, however, EF isn't telling me what field is causing the issue, nor any line of code!

The DB model is huge and I can't possibly eyeball all fields

How can I trace this properly? despite using --verbose it's still not returning any useful messages

Comment: Well, you know it is an `int`...

Comment: To pinpoint the issue, comment out half of the db sets, try again, check if the error occurs, dig deeper. This is effectively a [binary search](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/) and will help you pinpoint the offending entity.

Comment: the project is full of other stuff, it's been in production in years, so if I comment that I will have to comment out half of the project as well xD